# Is there any .Net P2P communication in RTMFP fashon library+server?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, cross-platform, p2p

So [Actionscript has RTMFP](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/) that can be used for P2P mesh network communication with [centralized server](https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus) that controlles open ports and gathers [peer IPs](http://cc.rtmfp.net/). Yet it [does not work for iOS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html) and it is Actionscript.

So I need a pure Mono/.Net P2P (or iOS compatable .Net wrapper of some C++ library that works across major platforms) network communication library + server that would allow to minimize server load to nearly none bringing all data exchange directly to clients.

Main use that I need it for is crossplatform (iOS as main target) gaming client application.  Is there any such solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some open source reverse engineering based solutions. All of them are not completely conforming with rfc7016 and rfc7425.
For server side there are two solutions:
1. https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus
2. https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaServer
There is currently no client based lib as open source. If you are interested in that solution, I have implemented server side and working on client lib in C for crossplatform.

Comment: That is exactly my point - at least 2 RTMFP servers and no C or .Net RTMFP client (that would be capable to work in P2P fashon)...

Comment: If you are using it for iOS then C static lib is what you need, I don't see what is the usage of 2 RTMFP servers in this case, maybe if you are planning to distribute servers across the globe for less latency and/or some other use cases. Also, if you are not planning to interoperate with flash players/air instances, then you would need some custom crypto profile for rfc 7016 because of licensing of flash profile for rtmfp (rfc 7425). What is your expected load for servers, number of users (one user MUST maintain one connection with server)?

Comment: And if you are using it just for peer introducing, you must plan for authentication on server side to avoid unwanted clients to overflow your server.